# Summation of a vector with multiple numbers into another vector

Tags: r

Lets say i have two vectors. One for the general vector i want to repeat in each summation, and the other as the container of the numbers i want to sum with the general vector.

```
general_vector = c(1:3)
container = c(1:4)
```

The result i want is:

```
c(1+general_vector, 2+general_vector, 3+general_vector, 4+general_vector)
```

So the output should be

```
[1] 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6 5 6 7
```

Basically i want to get a vector containing the summation of a vector with multiple entries. How can i achieve this?

Comment: `rep(container, each = length(general_vector)) + rep(general_vector, length(container))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `outer` :

```
result <- c(outer(general_vector, container, `+`))
result
#[1] 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6 5 6 7
```

and `sapply` :

```
result <- c(sapply(container, `+`, general_vector))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `Reduce` with `expand.grid`

```
Reduce(`+`, expand.grid(general_vector, container))
#[1] 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6 5 6 7
```